# Doubt in mathematical logic and how to negate a statement?

Tags: abstract-algebra, propositional-calculus

I want to prove the following proposition by the method of contradiction but how do I negate this statement

> Let $G$ be a group having exactly $3$ subgroups then show that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^2$.

$!$( $G$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$) $\implies $ G doesnot have exactly $3$ subgroups.

How do I negate the first statement?

Comment: "Let $G$ be a group. Assume $G$ is not cyclic of order $p^2$. Then either $G$ is not cyclic or it is not of order $p^2$."

Comment: What is your doubt?

Comment: I want to negate the statement but how do I proceed?

Comment: A proof by contradiction may turn out ot be overly complicated. After all, you'd want to arrive at "The number of subgroups of $G$ is either at most 2 or is at least 4" starting from "$G$ is not cyclic, or perhaps cyclic its order is not a perfect square, or perhaps is cyclic of perfect square order $n^2$ but then $n$ has a non-trivial divisor". So, I urge you to try a forward proof. E.g., if the subgroups are $1,H,G$ and you pick $a\notin H$, what can you say about $\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: Yes I have been able to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $G$ be a group having exactly $3$ subgroups then show that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^2$.

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $G$ has exactly $3$ subgroups.

Assume that $G$ is not a cyclic group of order $p^2,$ i.e., that $G$ is either not cyclic or not of order $p^2.$

When a contradiction is derived, we will have that “$G$ has exactly $3$ subgroups $\implies G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^2$”, as required.